# MYSQL: Which index should I create in the scenario given?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

Suppose,

I have a website that shows posts on the basis of **Tags**, **Date Uploaded**, and If the user has not liked that post.

I will create **fulltext** index on Tags column.

So, should I create index just on tags column 

**OR**

What should I create compound index(Muti column index) with all the columns or just single index with only the tags column? 

If the answer is Compound Index,

What type of index should I create? FULLTEXT? Will it work on the other two columns(Date and Likes)?

Likes is a JSON array and Date is just a `VARCHAR` COLUMN!

Comment: This really depends on how you will be using your columns in the queries you need. So to get the best advise show us some queries and data samples. In general the columns to index are those columns that are used in your where clauses, order by clauses or join statements. I would also suggest start reading about index optimalization and usage. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Show us a sample of a row in the table.  Of special note is how you deal with multiple tags, where you are searching for only one.  Do you have a list of tags in a single column or what?  And is a "like" stored by bumping a counter?  Or listing details of who and when the liking occurred.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is likely to be unnecessary complication.

These tables come to mind:

```
Posts:  post_id, date_uploaded, ...
Tags:   post_id, tag (a string) (one row per tag)
Likes:  user_id, post_id
```

Note that Posts:Tags is 1:many.  Ditto for Likes.

```
SELECT  ...,
        p.date_uploaded,
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) FROM Tags
            WHERE post_id = p.post_id
              AND tag = ?
            )  AS tags,
        IF( EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Likes WHERE post_id = p.post_id
                   AND user_id = ? ),
               "they like it",
               "they don't like it" ) AS liked
    FROM Posts AS p
    WHERE ...
```

Indexed needed:

```
Tags:  INDEX(post_id, tag) -- for "Which Tags does this Post have" (this query)
Tags:  INDEX(tag, post_id) -- for "what Posts have this Tag"
Likes: INDEX(user_id, post_id)  -- for "what Posts does this user Like"
Likes: INDEX(post_id, user_id)  -- for "which users Like this Post"
```